# Name validation using jquery validation framework

Tags: jquery, input, validation

I want to add a custom function using jquery validation framework, to help validating names (first name and last name) inside a form.

I understand I could just eliminate numbers... but wondering if there is a 'best practice' way using jquery validation framework, somebody could suggest me...?

Thanks

Comment: as per requirements... only letters, apostrophes and hyphens are allowed for the name fields

Comment: What about whitespace? Accents éêèà etc...? What about periods for "Don Jr."?

Comment: @Alex: not accepting Accents and the name fields are broken like ... first name is separate than last name (so no whitespaces) and there is no suffix. So ^[a-zA-Z'-]+$ worked fine.

Comment: Name validation is a bad idea. See http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used regular expression to validate the name fields on the form : ^[a-zA-Z'-]+$
using the jquery.validator.addMethod